# How to put a second value by leaving one space between the two values by text box?

Tags: c++, text-files, c++builder

I have one Text Box and two floats named by: `float petrol, diesel;`. I was able to enter the value for petrol, but how can I enter another value by leaving one space with the same Text Box?

My code:

```cpp
 void __fastcall TForm1::Button2Click(TObject *Sender) {
           
    float petrol, diesel;

    petrol = StrToFloat(Form1->Edit2->Text);
    diesel = StrToFloat(Form1->Edit2->Text);

    ofstream price;
    price.open("price.txt", ios::app);

    if (price.is_open()) {

    price << "Petrol price is: " << petrol << "\n";
    price << "Diesel price is: " << diesel << "\n";
 }
```

This is error message that comes to me, when trying to put the second value of `float(diesel)` in text box:
'1.5 2.5' is not a valid floating point.

Comment: Have you noticed that you are reading the same input field twice? `StrToFloat` is not a standard function, so you should have added its definition – maybe it is using some static stream that is not cleared properly?

Comment: This function ``StrToFloat`` is only change text box type to float, so the problem isn't in that. @Aconcagua

Comment: I want to assign two ``floats`` by one space between them in same text box

Comment: StrToFloat is correctly telling you that 1.5 2.5 is not a valid floating point. The normal C++ Builder solution to tis would be to use two text boxes, one for each parameter. If you must use a space separated pair then you need to read in the text as a String into a String variable and then parse this to separate out the two parts that you need for your two values.

Comment: @DaNGeRouSGaMeR This is suspiciously similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67373543/) asked yesterday. Are you @HumamAl-Zaydi? If so, please don't post questions using multiple accounts.

Comment: So how the code will be please? @RogerCigol

Comment: There are many ways to convert strings to values. One way might be to use a `std::istringstream`: `std::istringstream in("1.5 2.5"); if(in >> petrol >> diesel) {/* parsing was OK */ }`

Comment: @DaNGeRouSGaMeR As alternative, put two dinstinct `TEditBox`es, and use TAB key to switch one another? You could even place a couple `TLabel`s with caption "petrol" and "diesel"